# Android Chatting Application best approach

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, instant-messaging

I am new to android and i want to build a chatting application in android. I have read many articles on it in which people has suggested me to select one of following methods in order to create chat-application in android

1) Socket Programming
2) Push Notification etc
but before starting the work on it i want to get your opinions how should i proceed

Buddies I have two questions

1) **Regarding Front-end designing**:

what is the best approach to design chat-box in order to show conversation?
most of the developers have used "ListView+Adapter" method to show a conversation between two users in which each message is a list item, another developer has used scroll view to show conversation, i am sure first approach is better than second, is there any other optimal way to become an efficient app like whats-app/facebook Messenger?

2) **Regarding backend Support**:
   Let suppose my app users are in thousands figure like 5,000-10,000 and if i use push notification method(FCM service) then do you think my app will still work perfectly?

I will be very thank full to you..

Answer (score 0):

1) I think ListView and adapter could be a better solution;

2) think that when you interact with a Database getting a lot of items (in your SELECT Query result), you can easily establish a limit of results for your query (keeping track of the "page" of results you are showing), so you can show into your listview a limited number of users and messages per time.

Comment: thanks for your response i just want to know that is this a usual approach in android to show messages by using Listivew and adapter?

Comment: and what is your opinion about FCM for chat?

Comment: I've never used FCM, but as a principle a noSQL database it's well designed to treat data such as comments, messages etc. So probably it's a valid alternative to classic SQL Database, like MySQL (see this tutorial which is very interesting: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/ )